# NET MAUI Incorporate Android native control with XML layout

Tags: android, .net, controls, maui, native

I am beginning with NET Maui and i try to incorporate an Android native control defined by an xml layout in a .NET Maui ContentPage.
I have put the XML (Test2.xml) in the following path : Platforms -> Android -> Resources -> drawable.
But I can't figure out how to display it from my ContentPage, either in XAML or C#. Could someone can help me ? Thanks in advance

[image: Solution Explorer]

I have tried to use handlers but it's very difficult for me to understand how it works.

Comment: Have you checked out how to [create custom controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create)?

Comment: Gerald Versluis's tutorial video ([Porting your Xamarin.Forms Custom Renderer to .NET MAUI Handler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWdilOWAEt4)) can be useful.